# Apache SSL3_ACCEPT:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

Tags: ssl, apache2

One of our clients is complaining that they cannot access our ssl webserver. We are using Ubuntu 12.04, Apache 2.2.22 and our OpenSSL-version is 1.0.1. Apache error log is saying the following:

```
[error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Re-negotiation request failed
[error] SSL Library Error: 336068946 error:14080152:SSL routines:SSL3_ACCEPT:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled
```

According to Apache access log they are using very old browsers. I have read that adding "SSLVerifyClient optional" and "SSLInsecureRenegotiation on"-options will fix this problem. However, Apache error log is still giving us this error.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   SSLEngine on
   SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
   ....
   ....
   SSLVerifyClient optional
   SSLInsecureRenegotiation on
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there something wrong with our virtualhost configuration? Since our client won't fix this at their end, is there something else we could try besides this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Our virtualhost configuration contained also the following SSLCipherSuite-directive:

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
```

By removing this line and using the default SSLCipherSuite-directive resolved this problem.

Comment: Setting `SSLCipherSuite DEFAULT` works. One can also use the [config generator from mozilla](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) to get an up to date listing of SSLCipherSuite entries that can be copy pasted.

Comment: This line is important for disallowing insecure cipher suites. If you don't understand this concept then I would strongly advise you to study up on internet crypto basics. Be careful to edit this line appropriately.

Comment: Downvote because as previously mentioned by gillytech

Answer (score 0):

Setting SSLInsecureRenegotiation to on should work, are you sure you are in the right virtualhost? You can use apache2ctl -S to see all the currently configured virtual hosts.

Please note that using  SSLInsecureRenegotiation on makes **all** your customers vulnerable to a MITM attack.

Comment: Good on the warning about using renegotiation. I would not advise cutting back security for ALL connections to allow old (and insecure) browsers. Depending on the circumstance, the client should be advised to upgrade their browser to something more secure. The benefits may need to be communicated regarding this.